# Мне нужно сделать повторение ботом моего сообщения в другой канал в дискорде

Tags: discord.py

Я написал этот код, но бот не принимает большое количество аргументов, только два или лишь один. Как сделать чтобы он мог принимать много аргументов? Вот код:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("да")
async def type(ctx, *arg):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(client.get_channel(665127612934389765), arg)
```

И вот ошибка, которую выдаёт этот код:

```
TypeError: Messageable.send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Помогите поправить

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно пересылать ваши сообщения из какого-то определённого каналами, то добавьте доп.проверку

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == ваш ид:
        await bot.get_channel(665127612934389765).send(message)
```